# Which is better to prefer: overload or unique method name

Tags: java

I have a utility class and how I wrote it originally:

```
class UtilsWithOverloading {
    public static <T extends Item> T fill(T item, String name) {
          item.setName(name);
          return item;
    }

    public static <T extends Item> T fill(T item, Long id) {
          item.setId(id);
          return item;
    }

    public static <T extends Item> T fill(T item, Double diameter) {
          item.setDiameter(diameter);
          return item;
    }
}
```

But in this class there were problems when testing, when I passed the second parameter to null.
After which I decided to rewrite this class using primitives:

```
class UtilsWithOverloadingWithPrimitive {
    public static <T extends Item> T fill(T item, String name) {
          item.setName(name);
          return item;
    }

    public static <T extends Item> T fill(T item, long id) {
          item.setId(id);
          return item;
    }

    public static <T extends Item> T fill(T item, double diameter) {
          item.setDiameter(diameter);
          return item;
    }
}
```

But also this class can be rewritten without using overload:

```
class UtilsWithUniqNaming {
    public static <T extends Item> T fillByName(T item, String name) {
        item.setName(name);
        return item;
    }

    public static <T extends Item> T fillById(T item, Long id) {
        item.setId(id);
        return item;
    }

    public static <T extends Item> T fillByDiameter(T item, Double diameter) {
        item.setDiameter(diameter);
        return item;
    }
}
```

My question is, what is better to use exactly in my case?
Share your experience, which class will be more optimal in Java code

```
class Item {
    private String name;
    private Long id;
    private Double diameter;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Double getDiameter() {
        return diameter;
    }

    public void setDiameter(Double diameter) {
        this.diameter = diameter;
    }
}
```

Comment: it’s probably too opinion-based to be a good Stack Overflow question, and also we don’t know your domain well enough to give super-qualified answers. My immediate gut feeling is that the methods aren’t really variants of the same method and hence in this case don’t deserve to have the same name. It’s always a question of balancing pros and cons, there is no rule.

Comment: Overload is preferable. Unique method names for the purpose of avoiding overloading only creates more method names that cause confusion.

Comment: Overload is better but again as already suggested.,your question is asking for an opinion.

Comment: I agree with Ole. I'd add that I don't really understand the point of those methods in the first place. A caller that has an Item can just call setDiameter() or setId(). Why would he bother calling a static fill() method doing the same thing? And why are the methods generic, since they could just take an Item as argument.

Comment: My **opinion** - there's no ambiguity as to what gets invoked when each method has it's own unique name.

Comment: if your methods doing the same thing then go with overloading, if it behaves differently for each method then do unique method name.

Comment: I will go with unique method names but change name to setItemId, setItemName, setItemDiameter.

Comment: What would you do if you had to add a setRadius(Double radius) (for example) to your Item, and the corresponding static method in your utility class? You see that overloading clearly doesn't scale. It only makes the code harder to understand (what does fill do when you pass a Double?), and it's only possible because you happen to have 3 fields of different types here. Clearly not a good case for overloading. But again, these methods should simply not exist IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case i would prefer to have different unique method names, since your example is basically depends on the second parameter.

I would only use function overloading if my function takes different number of parameters.